# Query in order to select only the first record

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, how can I select only the first record from a table containing multiple records for each `CustomerID`?

Sample data:

```
CustomerID | Name     | Email              | Phone
123        | Emiliano | emilaino@gmail.com | null
123        | null     | emi@gmail.com      | 334455667
123        | Emiliano | null               | 334455667
110        | Pippo    | pippo@gmail.com    | 3232312
110        | Pippo    | null               | 3232312
110        | Pippo    | pippo@gmail.com    | null
```

Desired results:

```
123 | Emiliano | emilaino@gmail.com | null
110 | Pippo    | pippo@gmail.com    | 3232312
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.  There is no such thing as "the first record" because SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Ordering is only provided explicitly through a column.

Comment: In addition to what @GordonLinoff said, are you looking for a single record on the table, or the "first" record for each `CustomerID`? How do you define "first"?

Comment: I find that this question is clear and several other people have attempted to answer.  I understand neither why it was downvoted nor why it was closed.  (The question *could* be improved, but that is a different matter.)

Answer (score 1):

This should do.

```
select top (1) *
from [tablename]
where CustomerID = @customerID
```

P.S. based on your example, you may need to re-think  how you store the data, it's not clear which row is the valid one. you can add an order by clause to above to sort the data based on e-mail or name to get correct row

Answer (score 0):

If you have an identity column that specifies the ordering, you can get the "first" record for each customerid using a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.id = (select min(t2.id) from t t2 where t2.customerid = t.customerid);
```

Comment: Yes, I have an identity column and  your solution works properly.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The query below will allow you to select all the records from customerID

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE CustomerID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see below query. You can use `Over` in SQL for that.

```
select *
from (
    select *
        , row_number() over (partition by CustomerID order by CustomerID) as Rownum 
    from table
) t
where t.CustomerID = yourcustomerid and t.Rownum = 1;
```